# Apache Pig: Flatten column names after join

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, apache-pig

Say I do a join like this:

```
A = load 'inputa' as (f1,f2,f3,f4);  
B = load 'inputb' as (f1,f2,f5,f6);  

J = join A by (f1,f2) left outer, B by (f1,f2);
```

What is the simplest way to arrive at J's field names being `f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6`? (as opposed to `A:f1, A:f2, A:f3, A:f4, B:f1, B:f2, B:f5, B:f6`)

I know I can do the following:

```
C = foreach J generate A:f1 as f1, A:f2 as f2, A:f3 as f3, A:f4 as f4, B:f5 as f5, B:f6 as f6;
```

But I run into situations where I have a lot of columns following the join, so writing that all out is impractical. Is it something I should use a UDF for? I'm a pig novice and could use some guidance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `f1` and `f2` become ambiguous names in `J`.

If you don't want to rename the columns after the fact (and btw, you only really need to rename the ambiguous columns), then perhaps you could rename them before.

```
A = load 'inputa' as (f1,f2,f3,f4);  
B = load 'inputb' as (f1B,f2B,f5,f6); 
J = join A by (f1,f2) left outer, B by (f1B,f2B);
```

Now the names `f1` and `f2` are no longer ambiguous and you don't have to refer to the original alias (however, they are now both in the new alias which can grow quite large if you keep joining).